# What kind of set contains only cluster/accumulation point?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

If a set contains only cluster points, is it necessarily an interval? What can we say about this kind of set?
Can I classify a set by "contains cluster points only"/"contains isolated points only"/"contains both"?
Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: No to your first question;  take the [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), for instance.

Comment: I assume by cluster points you mean limit points. A set which contains only isolated points is a discrete set. And a set which contains only cluster points and is closed, then it consists precisely of all of its cluster points and is called *perfect*.

Comment: An empty set contains only cluster points and only isolated points.

Comment: I'm not sure if the terminology is standard, but in Rudin, sets that are closed and where every point is an accumulation point are called perfect. As others have said, there are examples that are not intervals. There is also a proof that in a metric space, any non-empty perfect set is uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a metric space $(M,\rho)$. Recall that we say $x\in M$ is a cluster point of a set $A$ if for each neighborhood $N$ of $x$, $N\cap A$ is infinite. Alternatively, every punctured neighborhood $N'$ of $a$ has nonempty intersection with $A$. You might already know that we can show or define a set to be closed if it contains all its cluster points. On the other hand, we say a set is *perfect* if it is closed, and all its points are cluster points of the sets. An example of a *perfect* set is the Cantor set. This set, moreover, is uncountable and has measure zero. A set that contains only isolated points is usually said to be discrete.